# does Spark support multiple AWS credentials for different paths under the same S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-spark

This is the use case: we want to join tables that are under different paths of the same S3 bucket; these tables belong to different owners and hence each has its own AWS crendtials (access key/secret/session token) for access, the data and its access is provided to us and we cannot change. How can I achieve this in Spark?

I understand Spark supports specifying per-bucket credentials in the SparkContext config [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configurations_different_S3_buckets); it does not apply to this case though since the tables are in the same S3 bucket.

Also there is an inefficient approach that downloads all tables to Spark driver, executors read data from the driver. But do we have a better way to use mul
tiple AWS credentials for the same S3 bucket, so that executors can read directly from S3 and the Spark driver will not be the bottleneck? thanks,

I also found a similar question was asked 3 years ago, not sure if it has changed [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400325/spark-using-multiple-credentials-for-the-same-s3-bucket)

I've tried setting the AWS credentials in Spark config like below, and use it to create a Spark session. After reading table 1 successfully, we update the SparkConfig with the same approach using AWS credential for table 2; however Spark config does not accept this update and still use the table 1 credentials when accessing table 2.

`hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration() hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider") hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", '***') hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", '***') hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", "***")`